# Is it possibile customize the actions added by bake (CakePHP 3)?

Tags: cakephp-3.x, cakephp-bake

I want to be able to bake controllers and views without using the "view" action.
Is there any parameter or way to skip or even customize the actions for bake commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can use events to modify bake's behaviour.

Add the following code to `bootstrap_cli.php`

```php
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Event\EventManager;
use Cake\Utility\Hash;
// put all 'use' statements at the top of the file

EventManager::instance()->on(
    'Bake.beforeRender.Controller.controller',
    function (Event $event) {
        $view = $event->getSubject();
        if(!empty($view->viewVars['actions'])) {
            $messages = $view->viewVars['actions'];
            $del_val = 'view';
            if (($key = array_search($del_val, $messages)) !== false) {
                unset($messages[$key]);
                echo "\n";
                echo '====== NOTICE ======' . "\n";
                echo 'Removed view action.' . "\n";
                echo '====================' . "\n";
            }
            $view->viewVars['actions'] = $messages;
        }
    }
);
```

More info at: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html

Also check: https://github.com/cakephp/bake/issues/164